# How to remove an empty string from an array. I am not sure weather it is from PHP or Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am using Ajax in order to display drop-down list when a product group is selected. My Ajax returns a list from the query page(dropd.php). However the problem is the array consists of some empty space between each element. Hence when I did inspect in chrome below is the output I am getting,

```
<option value="1">Gear pumps</option>
<option></option>
<option value="2">Piston pumps</option>
<option></option>
```

How could I remove `"<option></option>"` from the drop-down list? If I take option tag out from html what I receive is;

Gear pumps^piston pumps^vane pumps...etc
If you can notice the space(^).

**Ajax code**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#sel1').on('change', function(){
          $.post("dropd.php",{vals:$("#sel1 option:selected").text()},
          function(data){$.trim($("#sel2").html( data ));});
         });
    });
</script>
```

**dropd.php**

```
<?php 
  require('../config/connection.php'); 
  if($_POST['vals']){   
  $values = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,$_POST['vals']);
  $query = "SELECT * FROM prdct_categories WHERE product = '$values'";
  $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
  ?>
    <option value="">Select subgroup</option>
    <?php
    foreach($result as $row)
    { ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['subgroup']; ?><option/>        
       <?php
        }
     }
    mysqli_close($dbc);
  ?>
```

**Ajax data goes here**

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputsubprdctgrp" class="col-sm-4 control-label" >Product Subgroup</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <select class="form-control" id="sel2" >

        </select>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: <option value="1">Gear pumps</option>
<option></option>
<option value="2">Piston pumps</option>
<option></option> 

Is this dynamic ? ?

Comment: Does the `<option/>` (in the `foreach` loop) is intentional or it should be `</option>`?

Comment: ^^ Yes, that's the issue. The markup is incorrect and you add an empty option with each `<option/>`. Chrome is attempting to correct the invalid markup by closing the previous `<option>` before inserting the empty one.

Comment: How about query like this: `SELECT * FROM prdct_categories WHERE product = '$values' and product != ''`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be 2 issues:

1. The SQL result gives an empty value which can be fixed by using the array_filter() method:

   $new_result = array_filter($result);
2. You wrote **option/** instead of **/option

Hope this helps :)

Comment: How about query like this: `SELECT * FROM prdct_categories WHERE product = '$values' and product != ''`

Comment: @RayonDabre hope you dont program like that because its ugly and you put a risk of SQL Injection

Comment: _Ugly_ ? How ? SQL Injection ? How ?

Comment: $value = "1' ; DROP TABLE prdct_categories --";

I put this instead in your query and you screwed :)

Comment: Aah....My edit in the existing query was '__and product != ''__' Will this cause any injections ?

Answer (score 0):

Just use `

$('#sel2').find('option:empty').remove();`

after you load content from ajax, 
if you want to do it in javascript, otherwise avoid it in PHP in the first place.

Comment: He is loading the options dynamically so better to do it from PHP side. .

Comment: He has asked for any of the options, and i answered for javascript :) don't know why I was downvoted

Comment: same here , i thought he is rendering the data from PHP . even i was downvoted for nothing ,

Comment: i guess i know you buddy , i guess you gave me an the day before yesterday ,  remember  ??

Comment: @Ammar Hasan your code did work for me :-). but wd you be able to advice how cd I eliminate this from PHP rather than in Jquery.

Comment: @GautamPBehera  i guess you use Ammar Hasan's code after you load the data from ajax,. and append it to select box.

Comment: i think punit's answer should work for you in PHP, i.e. you should avoid generating html with empty option tags.

Comment: yes @PunitGajjar, i remember ur name from previous day but not the question :D

Comment: hahah , it was about to access the 3rd div having same class. and change the css . .

Comment: oh yeah, lol, that was a nice question though, I did it for the first time :) let's close this discussion here now, otherwise SO will close our accounts :D

Answer (score 0):

just dont put those values in options if it is blank..

you can use below code.

```
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
  ?>
    <option value="">Select subgroup</option>
    <?php
    foreach($result as $row)
    { 
        if(trim($row['subgroup'])!=''){
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['subgroup']; ?><option/>        
           <?php
        }

     }
    mysqli_close($dbc);
  ?>
```